# Unable to install rails with jRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to install the rails with jRuby with the following command

> jruby -S gem install rails -v 3.0.6

But stuck with the error :

```
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        from DefaultResolver.java:111:in `makeTime'
        from DefaultResolver.java:277:in `create'
        from DefaultResolver.java:317:in `handleScalar'
        from DefaultResolver.java:435:in `orgHandler'
        from DefaultResolver.java:455:in `node_import'
        from org/yecht/ruby/DefaultResolver$s_method_1_0$RUBYINVOKER$node_import
.gen:65535:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:146:in `call'
        from RubyLoadHandler.java:40:in `handle'
        from Parser.java:300:in `addNode'
        from DefaultYAMLParser.java:676:in `yyparse'
        from Parser.java:290:in `yechtparse'
        from Parser.java:284:in `parse'
        from YParser.java:152:in `load'
        from org/yecht/ruby/YParser$s_method_0_1$RUBYINVOKER$load.gen:65535:in `
call'
        from JavaMethod.java:630:in `call'
        from DynamicMethod.java:186:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
        from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
        from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
        from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
        from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
        from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
        from DefaultMethod.java:174:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
        from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
        from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
        from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
        from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
        from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
        from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
        from DefaultMethod.java:174:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
        from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
        from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
```

Anyone can help me to out of this error .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: have you tried the 'gem install jruby-openssl' line it says there in the error output?

Comment: yes I am able to install the "jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl"  But after this when I run the command to install rails it throws me the above exception .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem just a bit ago, but it was with `rspec`. Try this:
`jruby --1.9 -S gem install rails -v 3.0.6`

This tells jruby to use the ruby 1.9 interpreter.

Comment: That worked for me. Here is a link to the JRuby issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5581 It looks like this may get fixed in 1.6.2.

Answer (score 4):

This bug has been fixed in JRuby 1.6.2.

Workaround for JRuby 1.6.1 on the command line (Windows):

```
set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
# in your specific case
gem install rails   

# this is where I got the error (Rails 3 with Bundler)
bundle update
```

Comment: Yes, I got the same error installing Vagrant on Windows 7 x64 with jruby 1.5.6 installed.  Removing 1.5.6 and installing the latest (1.6.5) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This bug can happen with some versions of the gem you're installing, but not others. This is because the YAML error is due to the `date` field in the YAML file, as mentioned in [this comment for bug 5581](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5581?focusedCommentId=261532&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-261532).

For example, version 1.4.2 of the bio gem caused the exception for me.

Instructions for how to get the metadata are from [Shaving a YAML Yak](http://blog.rubygems.org/2011/08/31/shaving-the-yaml-yak.html), except I substituted gunzip and less for gzcat

```
gem fetch bio --version 1.4.2
tar xvf bio-1.4.2.gem
gunzip metadata.gz
less metadata | grep date
date: 2011-08-26 00:00:00.000000000 Z

YAML.load("date: 2011-08-26 00:00:00.000000000 Z") # Causes exception
```

whereas for version 1.4.1 of bio

```
gem fetch bio --version 1.4.1
tar xvf bio-1.4.1.gem
gunzip metadata.gz
less metadata | grep date
date: 2010-10-22 00:00:00 +09:00

YAML.load("date: 2010-10-22 00:00:00 +09:00") # Doesn't cause an exception
```

So doing `sudo jruby -S gem install bio --version 1.4.1` worked for me.

If you want the latest and greatest, then you could fetch the gem and modify its metadata, or build the gem yourself, but the above was Good Enough™ for me.