# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in arraycopy when installing roo gem with JRuby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, excel-2007, jrubyonrails

I am getting following error while installing gem roo in jruby.

```
C:\tibbr\svn\community_manager>gem install roo
System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        from DefaultResolver.java:111:in `makeTime'
        from DefaultResolver.java:277:in `create'
        from DefaultResolver.java:317:in `handleScalar'
        from DefaultResolver.java:435:in `orgHandler'
        from DefaultResolver.java:455:in `node_import'
        from org/yecht
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: I suggest you reformat this to a readable thing

Comment: i am too stupid to add all full trace. I tried to install 'roo' gem and i am using jruby. I got the following error. 'System.java:-2:in arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from DefaultResolver.java'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install rails with jRuby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045910/unable-to-install-rails-with-jruby)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

```
$ jruby --1.9 -S gem install roo
```

The problem should be fixed in jruby 1.6.2, as well.